# OTRS REST API with Python

Tags: rest, otrs

I try to use the REST API from Webservice OTRS. Actual I use python with the extention pyotrs, the request to OTRS found my configuration-File (yml) but there is the error "Session was not found on this server".

The documentation is really bad, I try this yml-File https://github.com/OTRS/otrs/blob/master/development/webservices/GenericTicketConnectorREST.yml
and try to do it manual, 
but nothing worked :-(

Has anyone experience with the configuration of the OTRS (5) webservice with REST?

Comment: Can you show some code? I've not used PyOTRS (it seems kind of new) but I did use the web service API. Please note PyOTRS first wants you to create a session before doing anything. https://gitlab.com/rhab/PyOTRS - and in OTRS in Web Services there's also a 'debug' screen which might help you as well.